# Authentication form problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization

This is a section from my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".MyCookie" loginUrl="~/Registration.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/">
    <credentials passwordFormat="MD5">
      <user name="user" password="ca064d0730abfeb09e383a0e82e65f73"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>

  <authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

This is the section in Registration.aspx..that the form doesnt show when the user is anonymous:

```
   <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/header.png" />
```

I dont understand why..But the picture is never shown :(

Comment: is the image in the website root?

Comment: yeah, it is  ..it is in the virtual directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in the web.config, in the configuration element:

```
<location path="header.png">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Oh, I see --- nifty.  I guess setting all access to some folder containing your media may yield some benefits :) --- I have actually never used Forms authentication (usually roll my own).